# split the captured group results in re.sub()

Tags: python, regex

```
InputString = r'On <ENAMEX TYPE="DATE">August 17</ENAMEX> , <ENAMEX TYPE="GPE">Tai wan</ENAMEX> is investigation department.'
p1 = r'<ENAMEX TYPE="(\S+)">(.+?)</ENAMEX>'
p2 = '_'.join(r'\2'.split(' '))
plain_text = re.sub(p1,p2,InputString)
```

Expect Output:

```
On August_17 , Tai_wan is investigation department.
```

Unfortunately, I get the result:

```
On August 17 , Tai wan is investigation department.
```

How to split the captured group `'\2'`?

Comment: is your actual input an xml document?

Comment: No, it is a string.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to just replace the matches with the second group (text between `ENAMEX` tags) and replace all spaces with `_`.

You may use

```
import re
InputString = r'On <ENAMEX TYPE="DATE">August 17</ENAMEX> , <ENAMEX TYPE="GPE">Tai wan</ENAMEX> is investigation department.'
p1 = r'<ENAMEX TYPE="[^"]+">(.*?)</ENAMEX>'
plain_text = re.sub(p1,lambda p2: p2.group(1).replace(' ', '_'),InputString)
print(plain_text)
# => On August_17 , Tai_wan is investigation department.
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/UY6llB).

Here, `<ENAMEX TYPE="[^"]+">(.*?)</ENAMEX>` matches `<ENAMEX TYPE="`, any 1+ chars other than `"` up to and including a `"`, then matches a `>` and then captures any 0+ chars other than line break chars into Group 1. Then, `</ENAMEX>` substring is matched. The lambda expression only pastes back the contents of Group 1 with literal spaces replaced with underscores. Note you may use `re.sub(r'\s', '_', p2.group(1))` in case you want to replace any whitespace char with an underscore.

Comment: Thanks. What is  the p2? why do the p2 have group(1)?

Comment: @futurelj `p2` is a Match data object here that is passed to lambda where you may manipulate the match object and only return the result after processing the match. `p2.group(1)` is the value that was captured with `(.*?)` (the first capturing group).